# What is the best practice for returning WCF Exceptions to Silverlight client?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, exception

I believe title says what I want to know. In most cases WCF Service returns `NotFound` exception, even if I handled exception in Service it returns something blah blah which is hard to realize what was the **exact** Exception. I want to know Is there any clean and good way to return exact WCF Exception to Silverlight client?

Comment: Do you mean a specific exception or all of them?

Comment: Actually specific exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is what you should do:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;
    ...
}

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, 
        ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Exception is YourException){
        //show a message box or whatever you need
        e.Handled = true; //if you don't want to propagate
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In **WPF**

```
public App()
{
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += 
        new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(
            Dispatcher_UnhandledException);
}

void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Exception is YourException){
        //show a message box or whatever you need
        e.Handled = true; //if you don't want to propagate
    }
}
```

You can check for the error property, as stated here: [Best way to catch a WCF exception in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94610/best-way-to-catch-a-wcf-exception-in-silverlight)

Or you can add a `Behavior` to your `ServiceHost` class.

```
public ServiceHost(Type t, params Uri[] baseAddresses) :
            base(t, baseAddresses) { }

protected override void OnOpening()
{
    base.OnOpening();

    //adding the extra behavior
    this.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ExceptionManager());
```

You then create a class called `ExceptionManager` like this:

```
public sealed class ExceptionManager : IServiceBehavior, IErrorHandler
```

and then a method called `ProvideFault` like this:

```
void IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, 
    ref Message fault)
{
    if (error == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("error");

    Fault customFault = new Fault();

    customFault.Message = error.Message

    FaultException<Fault> faultException = new FaultException<Fault>(customFault,
        customFault.Message, new FaultCode("SystemFault"));
    MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
}
```

---

### To use `ServiceHost`:

Create a class `ServiceHostFactory`:

```
public class ServiceHostFactory : 
    System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type t, 
        Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new ServiceHost(t, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

right click your service, select `View Markup` and add a tag:

```
Factory="YourNamespace.ServiceHostFactory"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Exceptions come from Services I don't think this can help to catch WCF Service exceptions.

Comment: @SaberAmani have you tried? unless you changed or are working with some modified proxy class it should work.

Comment: @SaberAmani By the way, I have a running example here for my MVC app using WCF and it works like a charm. My WPF app as well, the only thing I did was change to silverlight tech.

Comment: @SaberAmani check my updated answer, that's how I'm working with my MVC app.

Comment: How should I use that ServiceHost in my Service ?

Comment: @SaberAmani ServiceHost is a class that inherits from System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost. It exists so you can override OnOpening.

Comment: I know that exists, Where should I override its methods ? How should I tell my service to use MyServiceHost instead of ServiceHost